# glmnet algorithm in a different programming language

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

I'm trying use linear regression with elastic net penalties for a mixed model. In the past I have used the R glmnet package with the penalty.factors parameter to accomplish this, but R is no longer an option for my project. I have found several implementations of elastic net in different languages, but none which allow for different penalty factors for each feature the way that the R glmnet package does.

Does a true translation of the R glmnet function exist in any other language? Thanks!

EDIT: Note that the R code is actually a wrapper of the FORTRAN code written for the R package. A few other wrappers exist in other languages, but I am looking for an new implementation of the full algorithm, not just an alternative wrapper. I want to be able to edit the code a bit, but I am not at all familiar with FORTRAN.

Comment: To my knowledge no but I might be mistaken. `glmnet` happens to be based on one big FORTRAN function. Maybe, if you are really desperate, you look into translating it?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the options I am facing, but I was really hoping someone else had already done it.

Comment: googling "glmnet python" found [this](https://github.com/dwf/glmnet-python) ...

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes I have seen that. It's a simple wrapper around the same FORTRAN code. I'm hoping to find a new implementation I can modify. FORTRAN is also not a good language for my purposes, so I'm looking for something else.

Comment: You're almost certainly out of luck.  Since the algorithm isn't trivial, and the current implementation is well-coded in a high-performance language, and FORTRAN code can easily be wrapped by most modern languages, there's not a lot of incentive for people to rewrite it in another language ...

Comment: in general it's best to give a little more context in your question (what resources you have *already* found and what solutions, like wrapping FORTRAN, won't work for you [and perhaps why]) to improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: ... OK, I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I've tried to be more clear in my question now.

Comment: There is a pure [julia implementation](https://github.com/simonster/Lasso.jl) and it has [better performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4Zcud2vE0s) than the original fortran code

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed as it's definitely a useful one - but a pure JAVA implementation of glmnet is available here : https://code.google.com/archive/p/lasso4j/source/default/source, and a Julia implementation is available here : https://github.com/simonster/Lasso.jl, and a C++ implementation is made here : http://spams-devel.gforge.inria.fr/index.html

Comment: Ha and for Julia there is also https://github.com/JuliaStats/GLMNet.jl

Comment: Ha and for a C++ implementation see https://github.com/mchrzanowski/improved_glmnet

Comment: And for a minimal pure R implementation of glmnet see https://gist.github.com/dselivanov/b7504781eff75d884657

Comment: And this may also be of interest to you: https://github.com/jasonge27/picasso

Comment: Lastly, also keep an eye on this Rcpp version that is in the making : https://github.com/jaredhuling/ordinis

Answer (score 2):

I would have put this in comments if I had enough points, but there is an implementation in Matlab, written by a few members of the team that wrote the original glmnet package:
http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/

Comment: Thanks Allen, I did not know about this before. Unfortunately it is still just a wrapper around the FORTRAN code. As I have now clarified in my question, I am trying to find the actual algorithm in a different language.